# I'm trying to make chat program using Python 3.6 but I think I can't retain connection

Tags: python-3.x

```
import socket

host = 'address' # as you know this isn't letters but I just write it as address for now.
port = 50000
bufsize = 1024

server = socket.socket()
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen(5) 

while 1:
 print("Waiting Connection")
 client, address = server.accept()
 print("Connected")
 welcomemsg = ("send messages")
 client.send(bytes(welcomemsg, "utf-8"))
 print("client info")
 print(address)
 msgfromclient = server.recv(bufsize).decode("utf8")
 client.send(bytes(msgfromclient, "utf-8"))
```

---

```
import socket

bufsize = 1024

client = socket.socket()

while 1:
 client.connect(('address', 50000))
 welcomemsg = client.recv(bufsize).decode("utf8")
 print(welcomemsg)
 msgtoserver = input()
 server.send(bytes(msgtoserver, "utf-8"))
 msgfromserver = client.recv(bufsize).decode("utf8")
 print(msgfromserver)
```

I think I can connect server and client and then I can make server send a welcome message to client and client can receive that message.

But after that I think I can't retain connection between server and client any longer.

I want to make server and client retain connection after server send a welcome message to client and client send a message to server and then server send it again to all the clients (yes I am trying to make chat program.)

I am using Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. I see your code, but I don't understand what's wrong with it. Why do you think you can't "retain connection"?